# Angular: Return based on multiple conditions in component

Tags: angular

Im having trouble getting to the bottom/the most efficient way to return a true/false from a component to a template, to show/hide a button in Angalar.

Basically I have an Event object, which a user can join via a 'Join' button. The 'Join' button should only be shown in the current user isn't the Owner, hasnt already reqeuested and not been removed by the owner.

Current I have this in seperate methods in the component, to cut down code in the template. Also trying to use ternary operators where possible. Example

```
isOwner(){
   return this.event.ownerId === this.currentFirebaseUser.uid ? true : false
}

isRemoved(){
   return this.event.removedId.includes(this.currentFirebaseUserObj.uid) ? true :  false
}

  isPending() {
    return this.event.pendingId.includes(this.currentFirebaseUserObj.uid) ? true :  false
}
```

Then to show a button the function is

```
showJoin(){
if (!this.isOWner() && !this.isRemoved() && !this.isPending()) return true
}
```

The issues is that the event may not have the removedId array, so it will return back undefined. I get that but the only way round I can get to work is to turn these into if statements like so

```
isRemoved(){
if this.event && this.event.removed{ }
 if (this.event.removedId.includes(this.currentFirebaseuser.uid) return true
}
```

Is there a quicker/easier method to do this. I have also tried passing the event object back from template, and also using safe navigator operator ? in the template as I am getting the event via a subscribe, rather than async.

Comment: `return this.event.ownerId === this.currentFirebaseUser.uid ? true : false` is exactly the same as `return this.event.ownerId === this.currentFirebaseUser.uid` so the ternary is not needed

Comment: What should `isRemoved` return if `event` or `removedId` is null / undefined?

Comment: Ah yes, good point will change. Basically if there is no removedId, the user can't be removed so should return false and button can be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
isRemoved() {
    return this.event != null && this.event.removedId != null && this.event.removedId.includes(this.currentFirebaseuser.uid)
}
```

Please note that I'm using `!= null` as opposed to `!== null`. By using `!=` it will match both null and undefined

Comment: Ahhh perfect yes that seems to have done the trick , I have tried using the !== and using undefined but have just gone in circles. Thanks very much (y)